# Did the power armour from the Fallout 4 intro cinematic exist?

Tags: video-games, props, fallout

In the intro cinematic for the Fallout 4 video game a real human is shown in a suit of power armour.

Did this power armour exist as a real world asset (instead of being a CGI element) and if so is its current location known?

[image: Fallout Power Armour]

Comment: Are you asking if it exists in 'real life' as a prop? or are you asking if it exists as in... a nuclear powered battle suit under control of some government?
To be completely honest, its probably a composite rendering, where part of the suit is a real prop, and parts (such as the hands, they're a little big and too detailed for props) are CGI.